# Bevel complex edges

Tags: edges, bevel

[image]
How do i bevel this part in the middle? where 3 lines intersect.

with standart bevel, I get this result :
[image]

Comment: You might get a smoother result by reducing the angle between the inner beveled edge and that unbeveled edge leading to the left.
Alternatively, instead of the vertical edge leading up, bevel the one to the right, between the two faces that meet at an angle.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposition of topology:

[image]